# Can the empty theory (in the language of Peano arithmetic) imply anything?

Tags: logic

How can a theory, $T$ (a set of sentences in $L_{PA}$) which is empty imply something?

Is it stated and assumed trivially that it implies a sentence such as $\phi(x): \forall x : x=x$ is implied by $T$. I don't see how this is the case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: **All** the *valid* sentences in the language of f-o arithmetic are implied by the empty set (of sentences); in addition to Asaf's example, you can consider any instance of $\forall x \varphi \to \varphi^t_x$, like $\forall x (x+S(0)=S(x)) \to (0+S(0)=S(0))$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at your inference rules and logical axioms, stating that $x=x$, and that $\varphi\to\forall x\varphi$.

Or you can look at the completeness theorem, and note that in any model of the empty theory, $\forall x(x=x)$ is true, so it must prove that.